# get element id using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, getelementbyid

How to know which HTML element is clicked using javascript and get its ID?

I have displayed 3 labels dynamically using PHP for pagination- Page 1 , 2, 3 ,

```
<label id="<?php echo 'labelofpagination'.$z; ?>" value="<?php echo $z; ?>" >
<a href=# onclick="paginationlabelclicked(); "><?php echo $z; ?>
</a>
        </label>
```

Now i want that if 1 is clicked then 1-10 records are displayed , if 2 , then 11-20 and so on.For this i would run a MySQL query accordingly.

But how do i get the ID ,

Comment: Labels describe what form controls are for. You don't have a form control, so get rid of the label.

Comment: Labels don't have a value attribute either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try pass this to handler

```
<a href=# onclick="paginationlabelclicked(this); "><?php echo $z; ?>
    </a>
```

and then you can access id by using

```
function paginationlabelclicked(el){
  alert(el.id);
  // your code
}
```

UPDATE

In order that to be working you have assign id to anchor

```
<a id="page<?php echo $z; ?>" href=# onclick="paginationlabelclicked(this); "><?php echo $z; ?>
    </a>
```

and then you can access id by using

```
function paginationlabelclicked(el){
  alert(el.id.replace('page', ''));
  // your code
}
```

Comment: how do i get the value attribute of the label?

Comment: @sqlchild, you can get it by using `el.parentNode.value`

Comment: @Molecule : sir, its giving undefined?

Comment: @sqlchild, it's because `label` can't have attribute `value`. But you can get page id from `label`'s id. Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/98HRj/)

Comment: sir, does the value of label gets POSTED or not into the POST superglobal?

Comment: @sqlchild, no. Only names and values of `input`s get POSTED on form submission

Answer (score 5):

[Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/). Start with a working **link**.

```
<a href="myScript.php?page=$z" 
   onclick="return paginationlabelclicked(this);">
      <?php echo $z; ?>
</a>
```

Then your script can extract the value from the href attribute or the content.

```
function paginationlabelclicked(element) {
    var page = element.firstChild.data;
    // …
    return false;
}
```

It would be a good idea to [ditch the onclick attribute too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily send the id into the function called onclick, something like that:

```
<label id="<?php echo 'labelofpagination'.$z; ?>" value="<?php echo $z; ?>" >
<a href=# onclick="paginationlabelclicked(<?php echo $z; ?>); "><?php echo $z; ?>
</a>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, what you want to do is to get the text out of the `<a>` link that was clicked on so you can know what number the user clicked on and you can use that for your query.  Here's a jQuery version:

HTML:

```
<label id="labelofpagination">
    <a href="#"> 1 </a>&nbsp; 
    <a href="#"> 2 </a>&nbsp; 
    <a href="#"> 3 </a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#"> 4 </a>&nbsp; 
    <a href="#"> 5 </a>&nbsp; 
</label>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#labelofpagination a").click(function() {
    // get text, trim string, convert to number
    var num = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""), 10);  
    // go to that page here
});
```

And a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wesWd/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=# onclick="paginationlabelclicked(this.parentNode); ">
```

...

```
function paginationlabelclicked(el){
  alert(el.id);
  // your code
}
```